# How to fill the right location when new a children module in project in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module

[image]
when I fill it this way,it says directory has already taken by the parent project.

[image]
But I fill add this,it shows there is a redundant folder.

[image]
Just like the 3rd picture.

So how to build a module with brief directory using IDEA ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292362).

The fix is available in [2022.1.1+ builds](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2022.1+latest+builds).